# How to Power Bi DAX: Distinct count of rows based on date slicer?

Tags: powerbi, dax

[MOC Dokumentit Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fTsj.png)

I need to count distinct MF ID's from that table based on selected dates 'Luotu'

Range is select with slicer:
[Luotu-slicer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZkP6.png)

Dates come from Date table 'Dates (MOC)'[Date]

I thought that this would do the trick but no. I get 0.
[DAX Measure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMt8L.png)

Anyone?

Tried many different combinations and this the first one that does even bring zero.

Comment: Don't paste sample data or code as images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct measure looks like this:

```
Distinct IDs = DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'MOC Dokumentit'[ID] )
```

What remains is to establish a relationship between `'Dates (MOC)[Date]` and `'MOC Dokumentit'[Luotu]`. You need to make sure these columns have the same type. (Hint: Both should be `date`)

If you cannot create a relationship between your date table and your fact table, you need something like this:

```
Distinct IDs = 
VAR _min = MIN ( 'Dates (MOC)'[Date] )
VAR _max = MAX ( 'Dates (MOC)'[Date] )
RETURN
CALCULATE ( 
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'MOC Dokumentit'[ID] ) , 
    'MOC Dokumentit'[Luotu] >= _min , 
    'MOC Dokumentit'[Luotu] <= _max
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Both of your proposed solutions work!